# GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1Error.Failed: Unix process subject does not have uid set. Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, gdb

Hello ubuntu Community,

i have a Problem to open the root Folder or an application.
I use Ubunutu with the Virtualbox. I would be happy if someone could help me.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgbTz.png)